# Passing a parameter that could be null to a method

Tags: c#

I have the following method call and for some reason the syntax in C# is not working correctly. If the pkg.Library.description is null then set it to a string.."No Folder Selected". Is there another way to do this?

```
SendEmail (pkg.libraryfolder.description == null ? "No Folder Selected" :pkg.libraryfolder.description)

public void SendEmail(string folderdescription)
{
////
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SendEmail(pkg.libraryfolder.description ?? "No Folder Selected")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why what you have written wouldn't work, but another way to do this would be to use the null coalescing operator, represented with a double question mark, like so:

`var x = y ?? z`

If y is not null, x is set to y; if y is null, x is set to z.

Here is [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) on the operator.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain why your code isn't working, it should, my guess is either pkgs is null or libraryfolder is null.    Currently you are just checking if description is null, which will be an error if any of the other things are null.  So to fix that, try :-

```
SendEmail (pkg?.libraryfolder?.description == null ? "No Folder Selected" :pkg.libraryfolder.description)

public void SendEmail(string folderdescription)
{
////
}
```

or make it simpler by using

```
 SendEmail (pkg?.libraryfolder?.description ?? "No Folder Selected");
```